# Java Eclipse class not found exception (javax/media/opengl/GLCanvas)

Tags: java, eclipse, gephi

I am trying to implement gephi 3d atlas and getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLCanvas
at org.gephi.visualization.config.VizCommander.createCanvas(VizCommander.java:54)
at org.gephi.visualization.VizController.initInstances(VizController.java:138)
at org.gephi.visualization.VizController.getInstance(VizController.java:94)
at net.clementlevallois.ForceAtlas3D.ForceAtlas2.initAlgo(ForceAtlas2.java:156)
at org.gephi.toolkit.demos.MYSQLImportExport.script(MYSQLImportExport.java:113)
at org.gephi.toolkit.demos.PreviewJFrame.main(PreviewJFrame.java:100)
```

here is the ForceAtlas2 class implementation (error on last line):

```
    package net.clementlevallois.ForceAtlas3D;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.Future;

    import net.clementlevallois.ForceAtlas3D.ForceFactory.AttractionForce;
    import net.clementlevallois.ForceAtlas3D.ForceFactory.RepulsionForce;

    import org.gephi.data.attributes.type.TimeInterval;
    import org.gephi.dynamic.DynamicUtilities;
    import org.gephi.dynamic.api.DynamicController;
    import org.gephi.dynamic.api.DynamicModel;
    import org.gephi.graph.api.Edge;
    import org.gephi.graph.api.GraphModel;
    import org.gephi.graph.api.HierarchicalGraph;
    import org.gephi.graph.api.Node;
    import org.gephi.graph.api.NodeData;
    import org.gephi.graph.spi.LayoutData;
    import org.gephi.layout.spi.Layout;
    import org.gephi.layout.spi.LayoutBuilder;
    import org.gephi.layout.spi.LayoutProperty;
    import org.gephi.project.api.Workspace;
    import org.gephi.visualization.*;
    import org.gephi.visualization.api.initializer.Modeler;
    import org.gephi.visualization.api.initializer.NodeModeler;
    import org.gephi.visualization.api.objects.ModelClass;
    import org.gephi.visualization.api.objects.ModelClassLibrary;
    import org.openide.util.Exceptions;
    import org.openide.util.Lookup;
    import org.openide.util.NbBundle;
    import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
    import javax.media.opengl.*;
    import javax.media.opengl.GL;
    import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
    import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
    import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
    import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
    import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
    import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
    import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
    import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;


    /**
     * ForceAtlas 2 Layout, manages each step of the computations.
     *
     * @author Mathieu Jacomy
     */
    public class ForceAtlas2 implements Layout {

        private GraphModel graphModel;
        private HierarchicalGraph graph;
        private final ForceAtlas2Builder layoutBuilder;
        private DynamicModel dynamicModel;
        private double edgeWeightInfluence;
        private double jitterTolerance;
        private double scalingRatio;
        private double gravity;
        private double speed;
        private boolean outboundAttractionDistribution;
        private boolean adjustSizes;
        private boolean threeD;
        private boolean barnesHutOptimize;
        private double barnesHutTheta;
        private boolean linLogMode;
        private boolean strongGravityMode;
        private int threadCount;
        private int currentThreadCount;
        private Region rootRegion;
        double outboundAttCompensation = 1;
        //Dynamic Weight
        private TimeInterval timeInterval;
        private ExecutorService pool;
        private ModelClass nodeClass;
        private NodeModeler originalNodeModeler;

        public ForceAtlas2(ForceAtlas2Builder layoutBuilder) {
            this.layoutBuilder = layoutBuilder;
            this.threadCount = Math.min(4, Math.max(1, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1));
        }

        @Override
        public void initAlgo() {
            speed = 1.;

            graph = graphModel.getHierarchicalGraphVisible();
            this.timeInterval = DynamicUtilities.getVisibleInterval(dynamicModel);

            graph.readLock();
            Node[] nodes = graph.getNodes().toArray();

            // Initialise layout data
            for (Node n : nodes) {
                if (n.getNodeData().getLayoutData() == null || !(n.getNodeData().getLayoutData() instanceof ForceAtlas2LayoutData)) {
                    ForceAtlas2LayoutData nLayout = new ForceAtlas2LayoutData();
                    n.getNodeData().setLayoutData((LayoutData) nLayout);
                }
                NodeData nData = n.getNodeData();
                ForceAtlas2LayoutData nLayout = nData.getLayoutData();
                nLayout.mass = 1 + graph.getDegree(n);
                nLayout.old_dx = 0;
                nLayout.old_dy = 0;
                nLayout.old_dz = 0;
                nLayout.dx = 0;
                nLayout.dy = 0;
                nLayout.dz = 0;
            }
            ModelClass nodeClass;
            //nodeClass = org.gephi.visualization.VizController.getInstance().getModelClassLibrary().getNodeClass();
            //nodeClass = org.gephi.visualization.VizController.getInstance().getModelClassLibrary().getNodeClass();
            VizController vc = org.gephi.visualization.VizController.getInstance();
```

...

Project explorer + jars that I added to the buil dpath attached
any help much appreciated, thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Always ensure that you have only the correct version of `.jar` files in classpath**.

Otherwise, Classloader may find the wrong one and try to get the class file, which doesn't actually exist in it, but in the newer jar version. I can definitely tell that this is such a problem. Please try organizing the Classpath only with the required jar files.

Please find out the .jar file which has the same package without `GLCanvas` class.